# getFragmentManager from ArrayAdapter

Tags: android

I have a listView fulled from my custom ArrayAdapter. In each view there is a button. I want to change the current fragment when the button is clicked. This is my code:

```
public class CheckInSArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<JSONObject> {


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        return getViewOptimize(position, convertView, parent);
    }

    public View getViewOptimize(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ......

        viewHolder.commentBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

            ??? <<<<<

        });

        return convertView;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        ...       
        public Button commentBtn;
    }

}
```

So now, i can't invoke getFragmentManager from the OnClickListener. How can i do?

Comment: You can define callback in your adapter and pass an instance in at construction or you can checkout listView.setOnItemClickListener()

Answer (score 25, accepted):

OK, maybe i'm a bit late but, maybe it will help some people to do this.

In the class where you call the adapter, you need to extends or implements "FragmentActivity". Then your Activity will contain a fragmentManager.

When you call your Adapter call it with the class that extends FragmentActivity

```
MyAdapterName = new MyAdapterName(MyClassName.this, Objects);
```

Then in your adapter in getView() - do this.

```
final Context context = parent.getContext();
FragmentManager fm = ((Activity) context).getFragmentManager();
```

Be carefull to use the good android FragementManager
- android.app.FragmentManager
not android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;

Comment: is it possible to use android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;

Comment: @VV i don't know, but you can try, just replace the import with android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager and see if it's ok!

Answer (score 4):

its so late but here no one answered this question so.

you can invoke fragment manager in your getview method using

```
FragmentManager fm = ((Activity)context).getFragmentManager();
```

getFragmentManager() is a method of Activity class .

for example

```
holder.tvBuy.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{

@Override
public void onClick(View v) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     Fragment fragment;
     fragment = new Buy();
    ((Activity)context).getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame,fragment).commit();
}
}
```

here you need to pass  your activity as context to your adapter.

hope it will help someone....

Comment: This worked for me. The most valuable part was `((Activity)context).getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame,fragment).commit();` as I am used to just using `getActivity()` instead of creating one that way.

Comment: thank you ... you just saved my life :D 

I wanna know where did you get the idea ???

Comment: I mean do you have some url or doc to look at  .. just to understand what you just did

Comment: @Ayoub Good to hear, its helps. well i don't have any doc or url, because this code is a portion of one of my own project.