# Starting Fragment from ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

I have 4 Fragments that I'm using for my application. One of my fragments(ChatList) has a ListView that uses an adapter which extends ArrayAdapter. Now in my ArrayAdapter class, when a certain row is clicked I want to open up my CurrentChat Fragment. How would I go about this? As far I have looked, it seems as though fragments can only be accessed from activities and other fragments.

**ChatList.java**

```
package com.example.jj.fragments;

import android.database.DataSetObserver;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AbsListView;
import android.widget.ListView;

/**
 * Created by jj on 11/23/2015.
 */
public class ChatList extends Fragment {
    public static final String ARG_PAGE = "ARG_PAGE";
    ListView chatListLV;
    ChatListAdapter adapter;

    public static ChatList newInstance(int page) {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_PAGE, page);
        ChatList fragment = new ChatList();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    // Inflate the fragment layout we defined above for this fragment
    // Set the associated text for the title
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.chatlist, container, false);
        chatListLV = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.chatLV);
        adapter = new ChatListAdapter(getContext(),R.layout.single_chatlist_row);
        chatListLV.setAdapter(adapter);
        chatListLV.setTranscriptMode(AbsListView.TRANSCRIPT_MODE_ALWAYS_SCROLL);
        adapter.registerDataSetObserver(new DataSetObserver() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged() {
                super.onChanged();
                chatListLV.setSelection(adapter.getCount() - 1);
            }
        });
        fillChatList();
        return view;

    }

    public void fillChatList(){
        DBHelper db = new DBHelper(getActivity());
        db.getChatList(adapter);
        db.close();

    }
}
```

**ChatListAdapter.java**

```
package com.example.jj.fragments;

/**
 * Created by jj on 11/28/2015.
 */

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import io.socket.client.IO;
import io.socket.client.Socket;

public class ChatListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ChatListDataProvider>{

    public Socket mSocket;
    {
        try {
            mSocket = IO.socket("https://great-sarodh.c9.io/");
        }
        catch (URISyntaxException e){}
    }

    private static final String TAG = "ChatListAdapter" ;
    public List<ChatListDataProvider> chat_list = new ArrayList<ChatListDataProvider>();

    private TextView dateTV;
    private TextView messageTV;
    private TextView timeTV;
    private TextView sideTV;
    private ImageView PictureIV;
    private String gcmID;
    private String androidID;
    private String roomhash;
    private int side;
    CurrentChat CCFrag;

    int type;

    Context CTX;


    public ChatListAdapter(Context context, int resource) {

        super(context, resource);
        CTX = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void add(ChatListDataProvider object){
        chat_list.add(object);
        super.add(object);

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return chat_list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public ChatListDataProvider getItem(int position) {

        return chat_list.get(position);
    }


    @Override public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if(convertView == null){

            LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) CTX.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.single_chatlist_row,parent,false);
        }

        sideTV = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.sideTV);
        messageTV = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lastmsgTV);
        timeTV = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.timeTV);
        ChatListDataProvider provider = chat_list.get(position);
        gcmID = provider.gcmID;
        messageTV.setText(provider.lastMsg);
        timeTV.setText(provider.time);
        side = provider.side;
        if(side == 0){
            sideTV.setText("Who?:");
        }
        else if(side == 1){
            sideTV.setText("You:");
        }
        roomhash = provider.roomID;

        convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stuck
                Log.d(TAG, "JOINING ROOMID" + chat_list.get(position).roomID);
                mSocket.emit("CreateRoom", chat_list.get(position).roomID, chat_list.get(position).gcmID);
               //THE CODE TO OPEN CURRENTCHAT FRAGMENTS SHOULD GO HERE
            }
        });

        notifyDataSetChanged();
        return convertView;

    }


}
```

**ChatListDataProvider.java**

```
package com.example.jj.fragments;

import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

/**
 * Created by jj on 11/28/2015.
 */
public class ChatListDataProvider extends FragmentActivity{
    public String roomID;
    public String gcmID;
    public String lastMsg;
    public String date;
    public String time;
    public int side;

    private ChatAdapter chat;


    public ChatListDataProvider (String gcmID) {
        super();
    }


    public ChatListDataProvider (String roomID, String gcmID, String lastMsg, int side, String time, String date) {
        this.roomID = roomID;
        this.gcmID = gcmID;
        this.lastMsg = lastMsg;
        this.side = side;
        this.date = date;

    }

}
```

**CurrentChat.java**

```
package com.example.jj.fragments;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


public class CurrentChat extends Fragment {

    public static final String ARG_PAGE = "ARG_PAGE";

    public static CurrentChat newInstance(int page) {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_PAGE, page);
        CurrentChat fragment = new CurrentChat();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.currentchat, container, false);
        return view;
    }

}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18689727/getfragmentmanager-from-arrayadapter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to do that you can make a function inside your adapter passing your current activity context and container/frame layout like this.

```
public void changeFragmentFromAdapter(Activity act , int layoutid)
{
    YourFragment fragmentToPopulate =  new YourFragment();
    FragmentManager frgManager = act.getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fgTransation = frgManager.beginTransaction();
    FgTransation.replace(layoutid, fragmentToPopulate).commit();
}
```

Paste this function in your ChatListAdapter.
now in your ChatList Class add itemclicklistener to your list

```
    chatListLV.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                  //Here Add call change function
           adapter.changeFragmentFromAdapter(getActivity() , R.layout.chatList);
   }
}
```

i assume R.layout.chatList is your container for 3 fragments in MainActivity.
Now call this function from your activity of fragment.

Comment: Check my updated post. I want to add the code to start the new Fragment in my ChatListAdapter. I also got the following errors 'Cannot resolve method 'getSupportFragmentManager()'. @Arslan

Comment: This solution should work.just one prick.Are you using AppCompatActivity ?

Comment: No I'm extending Fragment in that class

Comment: i mean on which activity your fragment is? A fragment must always be on activity ? so which is yours?

Comment: My mainactivity has 3 fragments to it (Interest,ChatList,LiveFeed). However, in my ChatList fragment which uses the ChatListAdapter, I want to open a new Fragment called CurrentChat on top of it when a certain element is clicked in the Adapter.

Comment: this line fgTransation.replace(layoutid, fragmentToPopulate).commit(); gives me this error "Error:(124, 21) error: no suitable method found for replace(int,CurrentChat)
method FragmentTransaction.replace(int,Fragment,String) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
method FragmentTransaction.replace(int,Fragment) is not applicable
(actual argument CurrentChat cannot be converted to Fragment by method invocation conversion)" and also my activity_main.xml is my container for the 3 fragments. chatList is one of those 3. I want to add currentchat fragment on chatlist

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96452/discussion-between-revipod-and-arslan).

Comment: For this line " FragmentManager frgManager = con.getSupportFragmentManager();" it gives me this error Error:(123, 41) error: cannot find symbol method getSupportFragmentManager()