# How can I start a fragment transcation in ArrayAdapter

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm at a loss of starting a fragment transcation in ArrayAdapter which is called from a list Fragment. I have tried a few things based on this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18689727/getfragmentmanager-from-arrayadapter):

```
FragmentManager fm = getContext().getChildFragmentManager();
//The method getChildFragmentManager() is undefined for the type Context

FragmentManager fm = getContext().getSupportFragmentManager();
//same error above

FragmentManager fm = ((Activity) getContext()).getSupportFragmentManager();
//The method getSupportFragmentManager() is undefined for the type Activity
```

But none of them works, despite that `getActivity()` is passed when the adapter is instantiated in `ListItemFragment` class. Would anoyone please help me on this?

Class ListItemFragment:

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import com.model.ListItem;
import com.Data;
public class ListItemFragment extends Fragment{

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {     

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_container, container, false);

        ArrayList<ListItem> listItem = (ArrayList<ListItem>) Data.get();

        ListAdapter adapter = new ListAdapter(getActivity(), listItem);

        ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_view);

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        return view;
    }
}
```

Adapter:

```
import com.model.ListItem;

public class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ListItem> {

    public ListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ListItem> listItem) {

       super(context, R.layout.list_item, listItem);

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

       ListItem row = getItem(position); 

       final Context context = getContext();

       LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

       view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);

       //FragmentManager fm = ((Activity) context).getChildFragmentManager();

       //FragmentManager fm = ((Activity) context).getSupportFragmentManager();

       //FragmentManager fm = ((Activity) context).getSupportFragmentManager();

       FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();

       /*......buttonFragment = call a button Fragment.......*/

       transaction.replace(R.id.placeholder, buttonFragment);

       transaction.commit();

       return view;
   }
}
```

Comment: where are you actually building the fragment transaction?

Comment: Helix, I want to build the transcation in the `getView` method. I want to add some buttons and containers fragments to the list.  I have updated the post.

Comment: Consider using view instead of fragment. Having fragment within the adapter complicates it much if not something impractical.

Comment: are you getting errors or is it giving you null pointer exception? - also... I agree with Elye